# How to avoid recompiling on changes in *.scala.html files

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am using play framework v2.3. The problem I am facing is that any change in html and refreshing browser causes recompilation of the complete code. Can I avoid this?

Comment: Are you sure it's recompiling *all* of the code, and not just the template files? The Twirl compiler will compile your templates whenever a change is detected.

Answer (score 0):

Twirl templates are compiled, as [stated by the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTemplates):

> Templates are compiled as standard Scala functions, following a simple naming convention. If you create a views/Application/index.scala.html template file, it will generate a views.html.Application.index class that has an apply() method.

There is no way to disable this behavior because it works this way by design. My suggestion here is use `~` (tilde) before SBT commands so things will happen as you save the file, per instance:

```
sbt ~run
```

This will recompile the changed file (and possible others), every time you change and save it. Also, sbt has some options that can possibly help you here: `withNameHashing`.

See [sbt docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Understanding-Recompilation.html) to understand how it works. To enable it, add the following line to your `build.sbt` file:

```
 incOptions := incOptions.value.withNameHashing(nameHashing = true)
```